# Get 3 hierarchies in azure devops server query

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I want to get 3 hierarchies in azure devops 2019 query .

Example:

I have 2 tasks A, B  and one bug C.
Bug C is connected to task A and B ,I need to query throw task A to get task B
Is there a way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can get task B only if you use Parent-Child reference: Task A-(child)->Bug C-(child)->Task B. Then you can use a tree query: [Use a tree query to view hierarchies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#use-a-tree-query-to-view-hierarchies). If you use another link type, you can see these links only through Bug C and with a direct links query: [Use direct links to view dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies). Additionally, you can try PowerBI reports ([Work items with direct links sample reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-directlinks?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi)).

Comment: Thanks for the replay , but can i do it in one query ?

Comment: I am using Related link type

Comment: @EzraMekonen, in this case, we can not get Task B if we know Task A in one query. Azure DevOps does not support queries like that with Related links (only with parent-child). Therefore, you can use only direct links query and Bug C (as a known work item) in one query. I think you can try PowerBI reports [Work items with direct links sample reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-directlinks?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi) to combine links and get the right view.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get **direct** links of a work item from query. Since Task A and Task B don't have direct relationship, it's not able to get Task B from Task A via one query. You need to query through Task A to get Bug C, then query through Bug C to get Task B.